# "Stock" or "Stockwerk" as translation of floor?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, meaning

I am trying to understand if there is any difference between the words *Stock* and *Stockwerk*. They are both translated as *floor* and I am never sure about which to choose. 
Do you know if there is any reason to prefer using one or the other? Is there any difference in the way or context they are used? What would be more commonly used to translate the following two sentences?

> I live on the first floor.
>   This building has 5 floors.

Comment: Related: [Names and total number of floors in buildings: what is correct?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5749/names-and-total-number-of-floors-in-buildings-what-is-correct)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Stock](http://www.dwds.de/?view=1&qu=Stock) (*floor*) is a noun sometimes confusing even native Germans as it has 2 homographs in the meanings of *stick*, and *stock (supply, inventory)*.

We can use both *Stock*, and *Stockwerk* as synonyms but there are peculiarities on inflection of *Stock* in the meaning of *floor*.

When building a plural it is only used with numbers but stills stays *Stock* (unlike *Stöcke*):

> Unser Haus hat fünf Stock/Stockwerke.
>   Wir leben im dritten Stock/Stockwerk.

To overcome this, and when talking about plural forms without numerals is it recommended to use *Stockwerk* instead:

> Unser Büro erstreckt sich über mehrere Stockwerke.

Comment: Hm, ich würde durchaus sagen "Unser Haus hat fünf Stöcke", aber "Unser Haus ist fünf Stock hoch". Im ersten Satz klingt "fünf Stock" sogar falsch für mich.

Comment: I think, as an adjective, `fünf-stöckig` is accepted. That supports the expression `fünf Stöcke`, I guess.

Comment: @Em1: man kann das schon so machen und viele machen es sogar, aber es ist (zumindest heute noch) nicht korrekt. Der Plural von *Stock* ist *Stock* oder *Stockwerke*: *"Du musst noch fünf Stock höher steigen"*.

Comment: @Chips_100 It's written without a hyphen: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/fuenfstoeckig

Comment: @ComFreek thanks, good to know - I like how Duden has all number of floors from 1 to 10 as individual entries for `[x]stöckig`! :)

Comment: @Chips_100: No, *fünfstöckig* has nothing to do with the plural. The umlaut is there only because the word is an adjective derived from the noun. Just as in *eintönig*, for example, which is clearly also derived from the singular *Ton* not the plural *Töne*.

Comment: @HansAdler I see what you mean, thanks. I'm trying to think of a better example though, because `Ton` and `tönig` follows the same pattern as `Stock` and `stöckig`. Maybe `Schwamm`, `Schwämme`, but `schwammig`?

Comment: When you derive an adjective from a noun, it sometimes gets an umlaut and sometimes not. It is very rare for an adjective to be derived from a plural. *Eintönig* is obviously not derived from a plural because it means ***mono**tone*.

Answer (score 9):

When *Stock* is used in this sense, it has the irregular plural *Stock*. However, idiomatic selection between *Stock* and *Stockwerk* often prevents the plural of *Stock* from being used at all. (I have confirmed my intuition with Google's n-gram viewer -- as a statistical rule, not a strict one.)

- In the plural, always use *Stockwerke*.
- In the singular, use *Stock* when indicating or asking for the number defining an individual floor: "Im wievielten Stock wohnt Asterix? Asterix wohnt im ersten Stock."
- In the singular, use *Stockwerk* in statements for which the position of the floor in question is not particularly relevant: "Das ganze Stockwerk ist von Römern besetzt."
- Example of a borderline case: "In welchem Stock[werk] wohnen die Gallier?"

A synonym for *Stock/Stockwerk* that avoids the issue but may be considered slightly more formal (probably depending on the region): *Etage*.

Answer (score 3):

I would say "Stock" is a short form of "Stockwerk". There might be differences in usage depending on the geographical region (i.e German in Germany or in Austria, which differs in some ways).

"Stockwerk" and "Stock" are (based on my experience) used both in writing. Would have to conduct statistical research to find out, which is more common. I'd say either one is fine.

The first floor is special:

> I live on the first floor.

would be

> Ich wohne im Erdgeschoss.

whereas

> This building has 5 floors.

would be

> Dieses Gebäude hat 5 Stockwerke.

Comment: Careful with the numbering! The standard in the German-speaking area puts the first floor above the ground floor. However, some regions traditionally referred to the ground floor as first floor, and this numbering persists in old public buildings. There is similar confusion in the English-speaking world, making this example extremely confusing to follow.

Comment: I try to avoid this ambiguity when speaking German by using *Erdgeschoss* for the floor at ground level, *erstes/zweites/... Obergeschoss* for floors above that, and *erstes/zweites/... Untergeschoss* for floors below ground level.

Answer (score 1):

IMO the term "5 Stock" consists of a number and its unit; units are never pluralized in German language ! Would you talk about "5 Stöcke", that would make me think of 5 sticks somewhere, NOT of the level of a building.
To this extend, STOCK is a unit of a fixed meaning whereas Stockwerk/-e is a simple noun and will come in a plural form if needed... "5 Stockwerke hoch".